# RNG game in the making, need help determining the type of hit

Tags: javascript, java, class, random

Okay so I am making a program that fights a cpu, but everytime it rolls a miss first then a fatality, ill break down my code so it makes it easier for you guys to help out.

Imports:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
```

Setting up ints and the rng that determines the type of hits:

```
int life = 100; //Your life
int life2 = 100; //Enemy life
Random chance = new Random();
int rand = chance.nextInt(1)+100;
```

The types of hits and what they should do respectively:

```
while (life >= 0 && life2 >= 0){        
    if (rand >= 20 ){//Miss
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have missed your opponent like a fool.\nYour Opponent has "+life2+" remaining.");
    }
    if (rand <= 21 && rand >= 34){//Wiff
        int Wiff = chance.nextInt(10)+1;
        life = life-Wiff;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have stubbed your toe. Idiot.\nYou have "+life+" remaining."+Wiff);
    }
    if (rand <= 35 && rand >= 74){//Regular Hit
        int regHit = chance.nextInt(20)+1;
        life2 = life2-regHit;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have hit your opponent!"+regHit);
    }
    if (rand <= 74 && rand >= 90){//CritHit
        int critHit = chance.nextInt(40)+1;
        life2 = life2-critHit;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have dealt critical damage!"+critHit);
    }
    else {//Fatality.      
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatality!\nYou stabbed your opponent in the foot,\ndrug your knife throught"
                + "his belly,\nand impaled his head on your knife!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I'm willing to try anything, i am in desperate need to finish this guys, thanks for all help.

Comment: Check your >='s and <='s. They aren't correct. For example, you have an if statement that says "if (rand <= 21 && rand >=34)." This suggests it is possible to have rand be less than or equal to 21 AND greater than or equal to 34. Of course this will never happen.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `int rand = chance.nextInt(1)+100`, you are getting a random integer between 0 and 1, then adding 100 to it, so `rand` will be either 100 or 101. This is causing the `//Fatality` block of your if/else statements to be executed every time.

I believe what you want is `chance.nextInt(100)+1`.

Also, your comparisons in your if statements are incorrect. You need to switch the `<` and `>` in each of your if statements.

```
if (rand <= 20 ){//Miss
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have missed your opponent like a fool.\nYour Opponent has "+life2+" remaining.");
}
else if (rand >= 21 && rand <= 34){//Wiff
    int Wiff = chance.nextInt(10)+1;
    life = life-Wiff;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have stubbed your toe. Idiot.\nYou have "+life+" remaining."+Wiff);
}
else if (rand >= 35 && rand <= 74){//Regular Hit
    int regHit = chance.nextInt(20)+1;
    life2 = life2-regHit;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have hit your opponent!"+regHit);
}
else if (rand >= 75 && rand <= 90){//CritHit
    int critHit = chance.nextInt(40)+1;
    life2 = life2-critHit;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have dealt critical damage!"+critHit);
}
else {//Fatality.      
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatality!\nYou stabbed your opponent in the foot,\ndrug your knife throught"
            + "his belly,\nand impaled his head on your knife!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @KonstantinosChalkias, using `else if`, you can remove the `&&` piece of the logic completely.

```
if (rand <= 20 ){//Miss
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have missed your opponent like a fool.\nYour Opponent has "+life2+" remaining.");
}
else if (rand <= 34){//Wiff
    int Wiff = chance.nextInt(10)+1;
    life = life-Wiff;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have stubbed your toe. Idiot.\nYou have "+life+" remaining."+Wiff);
}
else if (rand <= 74){//Regular Hit
    int regHit = chance.nextInt(20)+1;
    life2 = life2-regHit;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have hit your opponent!"+regHit);
}
else if (rand <= 90){//CritHit
    int critHit = chance.nextInt(40)+1;
    life2 = life2-critHit;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have dealt critical damage!"+critHit);
}
else {//Fatality.      
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatality!\nYou stabbed your opponent in the foot,\ndrug your knife throught"
            + "his belly,\nand impaled his head on your knife!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It was the fact that i was using && instead of ||, im glad you reminded me to change this back though in a frantic attempt to solve the problem i changed that second guessing myself, thanks man

Comment: You don't want to use OR (`||`), you just need to switch your `<` and `>`. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding onto Andrew's answer,

It seems as though all of the if statements for your 'Hits' are actually impossible

```
if (rand <= 21 && rand >= 34){//Wiff
    int Wiff = chance.nextInt(10)+1;
    life = life-Wiff;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have stubbed your toe. Idiot.\nYou have "+life+" remaining."+Wiff);
}
```

The above will never be true as rand can not be both less than 21 AND greater than 34 at the same time, are you sure you don't mean to have OR statements instead?

Like the following:

```
if (rand <= 21 || rand >= 34){//Wiff
    int Wiff = chance.nextInt(10)+1;
    life = life-Wiff;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have stubbed your toe. Idiot.\nYou have "+life+" remaining."+Wiff);
}
```

Or do you mean for it to be:

```
if (rand >= 21 && rand <= 34){//Wiff
    int Wiff = chance.nextInt(10)+1;
    life = life-Wiff;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have stubbed your toe. Idiot.\nYou have "+life+" remaining."+Wiff);
}
```

Which would make a lot more sense

Comment: Thank you very much that was the issue, it was stated above with the rng being 101 but i changed that right before i posted the question and forgot about it, thanks man

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, your `if` statements overlap or are logically wrong. I guess you want to give some probability let's say 20% of missing the target, 15% 'stubbed your toe' and so on. You can actually simplify your code to not require `&&` by using if-else statements

```
if (rand <= 20 ){//Miss 20%
    ...
} else if (rand <= 35){//Wiff 15%
    ...
} else if (...){//for each of the following cases
    ...
} else {//Fatality
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh thats really sick, honestly ill probably wind up using this, thanks for bringing it to my attention